# Python: Where do functions/methods, like sorted, come from?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python. I have this sample program:

```
def main():
  a = [4,2,1,6]
  b = sorted(a)

  for i in b:
    print i
```

Where does sorted come from, or is this a python keyword of some sort? Same question with print i. This is python 2.7 by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sorted` is not a method but a Python builtin function.  They are listed here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, which is one sort of keyword.  In Python 3 it has been changed so that `print` is a builtin function.

Comment: Makes sense. So in 2.7, print is a statement that calls a builtin function behind the scenes?

Comment: @Justin984: Not really.  It is just a statement.  Statements don't necessarily call anything behind the scenes.  `print` does ultimately make use of `sys.stdout.write`, but there are aspects of `print` (like automatically inserting spaces and newlines) that are part of `print` itself and not `sys.stdout.write`.  In general statements have to be thought of as atomic parts of a program; you can't "get inside" them.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), it's a built in function.

Print is a statement in Python 2.7 - see the [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement). Note that's no longer true in Python 3, where print is now a function.